# Strange ALT key behavior running c4droid on my droid 3

Tags: keyboard

I am encountering a strange behavior while using ALT keys while editing a text file with c4droid on my Motorola Droid 3. If I use an ALT key to type a character such as `{` or `\`, the ALT key seems to "stick", and I am forced to type a character before I can type a normal keyboard character. No combination of keys seems to be able to deactivate the ALT key other than simply pressing one key, and having it output one undesired character. The output looks like

```
int main((nt argc...
```

instead of

```
int main(int argc...
```

Do I need to perhaps modify the keymap? How can I alleviate this problem? I hope I am describing the issue properly.

Comment: when you write a special character do you click on alt + button XXX or you click on alt then click button XXX ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf either - the difference doesn't seem to matter

Comment: android uses default maping from /system/usr/keylayout ,may be the answer is there ,does this problem happend only on c4droid or it happens every where ?

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf only with c4droid

Comment: I suggest you send a feed back to de app's dev ,the implementation of supporting physical keyboards is in the app it self ,or may be there is an option in the app's settings to remap or choose keys behavior

Comment: @lord-ralf-adolf I suggest you post an answer below, as your above comment is the solution to this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this behavior appear only in the c4droid app ,it isn't a system problem but a problem with the c4droid app ,I suggest you send a feed back to the app's dev ,the implementation of supporting physical keyboards is in the app it self ,or may be there is an option in the app's settings to remap or choose keys behavior.

**Email address of the dev:** n0n3m4@gmail.com

[C4droid's Play store Page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.n0n3m4.droidc)